# How to know the syntax of Unix command in Putty

Tags: unix

I have been using Putty since sometime now. I know there is a command 'info':

$ info command_name

This will give details of a command.

Similarly, Is it possible to get the syntax of a command?

Comment: man info or info --help

Comment: What about "putty --help"?

Comment: It may also be a good idea to check for an intro to Unix.  Forget about the client you use (putty) which is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.Let me make it more clear, lets suppose I am new to 'tail' command, I would understand what 'tail' does by entering $ info tail.  But information displayed will not provide syntax. So how do I know syntax of 'tail' in this case?

Comment: Putty used to be good for Windows, because telnet or ssh in Windows lacked or were terrible. Putty had a linux tools look. If you are in Unix/Linux OS, ssh command is good enough.

Comment: Try this "whatis tail".

Comment: For `tail` command you use `man tail` .

Answer (score 1):

You can get the syntax by entering **man command_name**
But it has nothing to do with Putty. Putty is just an interface to connect to the server.